# Sql query ...the change (increase or decrease) in total transaction amount from the previous day

Tags: sql

Consider the table containing the transactions of a restaurant
The table structure is like:

```
-----------------------------------------
transaction_id | date | amount
------------------------------------
1 | 2019-07-01 | 100
2 | 2019-07-01 | 120
3 | 2019-07-01 | 110
4 | 2019-07-02 | 160
5 | 2019-07-02 | 700
6 | 2019-07-03 | 120
7 | 2019-07-03 | 130
8 | 2019-07-03 | 140
…...
```

---

- transaction_id (INT) - Unique transaction ID for every row
- Date (Date) - Date of the transaction
- Amount (DOUBLE) - Billed amount

Question:
Write a SQL query to find the increase in total transaction amount on a daily basis. To clarify 
further, find the change (increase or decrease) in total transaction amount from the previous day

Expected output:

```
date | changed_by
-------------------------
2019-07-01 | 330
2019-07-02 | 530
2019-07-03 | -470
```

Comment: I asked you to change your question to reflect what you tried, not whether you tried ;-)

Comment: Which database/version are you using? Gordan's answer should work on almost all RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

You would use aggregation with `lag()`; the three-argument form is most convenient.  As the question is phrased:

```
select date,
       (sum(amount) -
        lag(sum(amount), 1, 0) over (order by date)
       ) as diff
from transactions
group by date
order by date;
```

Comment: Sql is not taking lag keyword

Comment: `lag()` is standard SQL supported by all the main databases.  You have no other indication of the database you are using.